# npm install no longer possible after deleting module directory

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

So I wanted to help out, and forked a Node-RED module to make some small contribution, but then got lost messing around with how to get Node-RED to run my fork (for testing) rather than the packaged version. Then I learned about npm's ability to install from a Github URL, which is nice, but it wouldn't work because I had already installed the module. Then I found I couldn't uninstall it either

```
npm uninstall original-module
npm ERR! path /home/nodered/.node-red/node_modules/original-module/package.json
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! errno -40
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open '/home/nodered/.node-red/node_modules/original-module/package.json'
```

so in frustration I deleted the module's directory, only to find myself unable to move forwards, or backwards. `npm install https://github.com/me/forkedmodule` fails with

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master https://github.com/me/forkedmodule.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d31dc53b
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d31dc53b': Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-08-22T01_07_18_257Z-debug.log
```

and trying to install the original with `npm install original-module` fails with

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules/original-module" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-08-22T01_09_56_127Z-debug.log
```

As you've probably guessed, I'm pretty new to Node.js, Node-RED and npm, but I haven't been able to help myself, so have to ask for help! It seems nonsensical to me that npm appears to be looking for a local copy of the package.json file belonging to the package I'm trying to install?

**Edit:** I should add that the above commands were all run as root.

Comment: edit package json to use github URL for that package, pointing to your forked repo, then just `npm i package-name`

Comment: I could do, but there is no such file - I deleted the module's directory.

Comment: Your project (where you want to use this package) should have package.json in the root, if it's gone you can recreate using `npm init`

Comment: What, you mean in the fork on GH?

Comment: No sorry I just edited comment, I meant the project where you're trying to include this forked version of a package

Comment: Ah. The "project" is Node-RED, which runs as it's own user "nodered". The Node-RED Node.js nodes are in /home/nodered/.node-red/node_modules - where do I find this package.json?

Comment: I'm getting tired of the word "node" btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152477/discussion-between-aarosil-and-ola-tuvesson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found a solution, not sure if it's the best one though!

In the "project" directory (`/home/nodered/.nodered` in my case) there's a `package-lock.json` file which lists the packages used by the project. In there I found an entry for the `original-module` which I removed, after which I was able to install the package "normally" with `npm install original-module`.

Then to solve the permission issue when installing from a GitHub URL, I found I needed to impersonate the "nodered" user with `su - nodered` (it's a password-less user in my case). As "nodered" `npm install https://github.com/me/forkedmodule` succeeded without any error. A little curious since I was trying to do this as root before, and got a permission error, but there you go. I also took the opportunity to `chown -R` the project's `node_modules` directory to `nodered:nodered` as I could see that was a bit of mess.

In future, I will try to remember to `su -` to my nodered user first, and navigating to the project root (again, `/home/nodered/.node-red` in my case) before running `npm install` anything. Hopefully that will avoid any further issues. Oh and a note to anyone else who just wants to contrib some quick changes to a module hosted on GitHub: to "pull" in changes you simply run `npm install https://github.com/me/forkedmodule` again - `npm` doesn't appear to provide any dedicated "update" method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case the solution was to delete the package-lock.json, delete node_modules, then reinstall npm modules.